# How can I have selenium (python) distinguish between similar links and click a link that changes?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium with python to click a link input by a user on a form that looks something like this.

> **Please link your facebook (e.g. facebook.com/xxxxxx):**
>
> facebook.com/sampleuserinput

I need a python script that only clicks the link provided by the user (facebook.com/sampleuserinput) and not the sample link (facebook.com/xxxxxx).

Both of these links are together in 1 text box (same xpath).

Answer (score 0):

There are two links in a text box?  Could you clarify or show some HTML?

I suggest you look at `elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("foo")` to get an anchor element by the text of the link.  Then click it with `elem.click()`.

There is all sorts of [good documentation for selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) with examples for a variety of languages.

Comment: Yes.  The whole form is basically an editable template in a text box.  The questions and answers are all in one text box.  I was thinking to use find element by partial link text, but they both begin with the same thing (facebook.com/). Is there some way I can tell the script to look for a link that begins with facebook.com/ but is not facebook.com/xxxxxx?

Comment: Sure.  How about you get all of the elements by partial link text and then use `get_attribute("href")` or `get_attribute("innerHTML")` to find the element that you really want.

Comment: I was thinking of using driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("facebook.com/") but that will give me the example link (facebook.com/xxxxxx) since that one comes first.  Is there something I can include that tells the script to not click that link and instead click the one input by the user?

Comment: Look, there is a `find_elements_by_partial_link_text` method that will return multiple elements.  You can the iterate over them and click the one you need after checking that the attributes `href` and/or `innerHTML` contain what you need.

Comment: The link I need always changes.  I just need to write something that isolates the sample link and clicks the other link instead.

Comment: You keep repeating yourself, but haven't demonstrated that you've tried anything.  I have told you exactly how to make this work, but I won't write code for you when you haven't demonstrated that you've actually attempted to solve your own problem.

Comment: The problem is that some people delete the sample url and some people don't.  I'll try solving it by slightly changing the sample url so that find_elements_by_partial_link_text will only give me the correct url.